# How to change constructor param type in Xamarin Android bindings

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

How to write a binding transform that will change type of constructor param?

Comment: You need to tell us what you've tried so far, and show any code you've tried first. Ideally show that you've done some googling around the topic first.

Comment: The question is rather straightforward - just a sample transform mapping that will show how to change type param in constructor.

I don't know what kind of "googling" proof do you want - my search history?

Comment: Just trying to help, historically questions that don't show attempts at solving a problem fail to illicit decent advice. That's all. No need to be snarky.

Comment: Thanks for -1 and not knowing the answer that was not snarky at all.

Comment: There's some documentation on how to bind a java library and adjusting the metadata to change the bindings, but without knowing what library/assembly that you're trying to bind there isn't a lot I can do to help. Starting points for messing with bindings can be kind of found at the following links:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5292/tweaking-the-transforms-files-for-a-java-binding

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

I'd suggest perhaps editing your answer to include some information on the specific java library you're using.

Comment: Thanks - this is the good starting point for a new discussion. Lets say its general question about the binding transform format that describes operation of changing constructor parameter from one type to another in any java library.

Answer (score 5):

Correct transform for changing constructor parameter type:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.test.test']/class[@name='TestClass']/constructor[@name='TestClass' and count(parameter)=3 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String'] and parameter[3][@type='java.lang.String']]/parameter[3]" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

Essentially, once you've located the right function with xpath, simply append `/parameter[index-of-param]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to preface this with the caveat that I have not needed to mess around with Java bindings in any extensive way so take this as a fairly generic answer. I'm also making some assumptions, primarily that you're binding a java library, rather than using a pre-compiled Nuget package that already has its bindings created by the Xamarin team. (Although the overall approach should be the same).

Assuming there's no way to perform any kind of run-time conversion of a method's parameter (granted this depends on its type and usage). Then you would need to find/extract the generated Metadata.XML file that will accompany the bound java library.†

This file contains all of the bindings required for the compiler to link the java libraries native object and type classes to the c# equivalents.

The Metadata.XML file will contain arguments that look like:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='{package_name}']/class[@name='{name}']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

After a bit of research I found the following useful links that help explain the syntax of these kinds of statements:

[Jon Douglas - "*Approaching a Xamarin.Android Bindings Case*"](https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb)

[Xamarin Documentation - "*Customizing Bindings*"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/)

[Xamarin Documentation - "*Java Bindings Metadata*"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/)

As to the specifics of your question, namely the type change of a parameter binding. You would likely have to add in an attr line to the Metadata.xml file  similar to:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='packageName']/class[@name='a']/method[@name='b']/parameter[@name='p0' and @type='String']" name="name">Classname</attr>
```

Essentially you define the package, class, and method name that you want to adjust the binding for, then using the name of the parameter as listed in the Java library, you simply set the type.

It's worth noting that the binding attr might already exist int he Metadata.XML file, if it is you should be able to either adjust the existing entry or recreate a new attr entry just below that should create a method overload with the adjusted parameter type....

---

† I will try to grab the exact location for this, to add some more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the nice write-up.

As you can see there are several types of transforms: visibility, name etc. 

I'm asking for a specific transform - changing type of constructor param. There are several examples of param type transform in methods but I'm struggling with constructor.

Comment: Thank you. It should be the same principle as far as I am aware, just where it asks for the method name you use the name of the class, that should allow you the ability to adjust the constructor bindings.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and get back with the answer.

Comment: Does it throw any kind of compilation exception, or does it seem to bind but not give you the new parameter type?